# @auth directive discards html block after @endauth

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-authentication

In a laravel app, I have a section of HTML where I want to include a section only if the user is authenticated. The section after that should always be rendered regardless the user is authenticated or not

```html
<div>
    @auth
        <invoice-form :items="items" :units="units" :invoices="invoices"></<invoice-form>
        <br>
    @endauth
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column has-text-centered">
            <h4 class="title is-4">Items</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-2 has-text-centered">
            <div class="toolbar has-text-centered">
                <span class="icon fas fa-sync"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue is, this only renders either the section inside the `@auth` or the section after the `@auth` block, depending on whether the user is logged in or not. How do I achieve to always render the section outside the auth block?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, unable to reproduce, the problem is somewhere else

Comment: I couldn't replicate it. How about using `@if (Auth::user()) xx @endif` if it works?

Answer (score 1):

My bad. The auth block actually included a vue-component. For simplicity i replaced that with dummy html code here. Problem was the vue component had a misplaced `/` character in the closing tag. That messed up the whole thing:
 `<invoice-form :items="items" :units="units" :invoices="invoices"></<invoice-form>`

Thanks for looking into it those who commented.